# How to properly use MIDIReadProc?

Tags: core-audio, coremidi

According to apple's docs it says:

> Because your MIDIReadProc callback is invoked from a separate thread,
>   be aware of the synchronization issues when using data provided by
>   this callback.

Does this mean, use @synchronize to do thread blocking for safety?

Or does this literally mean synchronization timing issues may happen?

I am currently trying to read a midi file, and use a MIDIReadProc to trigger the note-on / note-off of a software synth based off of midi events.  I need this to be extremely reliable and perfectly in-time.  Right now, I am noticing that when I consume these midi events and write the audio to a buffer (all done from the MIDIReadProc), the timing is extremely sloppy and not sounding right at all.  So I would like to know, what is the "proper" way to consume midi events from a MIDIReadProc?

Also, is a MIDIReadProc the only option for consuming midi events from a midi file?

Is there another option as far as setting up a virtual endpoint that could be directly consumed by my synthesizer?  If so, how does that work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you presume a function of this format to be the `midiReadProc`,

```c
void midiReadProc(const MIDIPacketList *packetList, 
              void* readProcRefCon, 
              void* srcConnRefCon)
{
    MIDIPacket *packet = (MIDIPacket*)packetList->packet;

    int count = packetList->numPackets;
    for (int k=0; k<count; k++) {
        Byte midiStatus = packet->data[0];
        Byte midiChannel= midiStatus & 0x0F;
        Byte midiCommand = midiStatus >> 4;

    //parse MIDI messages, extract relevant information and pass it to the controller
    //controller must be visible from the midiReadProc
    }     
 packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet);
}
```

the MIDI client has to be declared in the `controller`, interpreted MIDI events get stored into the `controller` from MIDI callback and read by the `audioRenderCallback()` on each audio render cycle. This way you can minimize timing imprecisions to the
length of the audio buffer, which you can negotiate during AudioUnit setup to be as short as the system allows for.

A controller can be a `@interface  myMidiSynthController : NSViewController` you define, consisting of a matrix of MIDI channels and a pre-determined maximum-polyphony-per-channel, among other relevant data such as interface elements, phase accumulators for each active voice, `AudioComponentInstance`, etc... It would be wrong to resize the controller based on the `midiReadProc()` input. RAM is cheap nowadays.

I'm using such MIDI callbacks for processing live input from MIDI devices. Concerning playback of MIDI files, if you
want to process streams or files of arbitrary complexity, you may also run into surprises. MIDI standard itself 
has timing features, which work as good as MIDI hardware allows for. Once you read an entire file into the memory, you can
translate your data into whatever you want and use your own code for controlling sound synthesis. 
Please, observe not to use any code which would block the audio render thread (i.e. inside `audioRenderCallback()`), or would do memory management on it.

Comment: But you did not mention about how to "pass it to the controller" so that it can be processed outside of this special midiReadProc high-priority thread.  Clearly I need to store off these packets into a data structure that the main thread can consume and turn into audio.  How does one properly do that?  Ideally I would like a multi-dimensional array so I can do packets[midiChannel][currentChannelPacketIndex] = *packet ... But I don't know how to tell how many packets total on a given channel so that I can properly allocate the memory for that storage.

Comment: @patrick, your assumption that the "main thread can consume something and turn into audio" either seems to have a wording problem, or isn't quite exact. Main thread takes care only of GUI updates as long as audio production/consumption is done on the real-time render thread, which is the most efficient option for timing. Concerning passing MIDI-generated data to the controller, if you just pass it as such, you still need a to decode the packets into something your render thread will understand. Your question is rather broad, I'll adapt my answer ASAP.

Comment: "Concerning playback of MIDI files, if you want to process streams or files of arbitrary complexity, you may also run into surprises."  -- that is my problem.  I am trying to stream a 185bpm midi file where the fastest note is a 16th, and it sounds like an absolute disaster..

Comment: My concern is that the timing of MidiReadProc event firing is in accurate..  I've made an implementation where I write midi packets to my synthesizer, and in a separate thread, my synthesizer polls, waiting for midi packets to arrive, and executes the note events, and output all of this to a buffer.  Once the midi file is done being played, the buffer is played and it sounds like a train wreck.  I've tried about many different implementations / approaches and none of them seem to work............

Comment: `MidiReadProc` isn't "firing" anything. Information you provide is not enough to conclude. Please read this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739756/coremidi-rock-solid-midi-sync). Do not call blocking functions like printf(), NSLog(), malloc() or Objective C method calls from any CoreMIDI I/O context such as this input callback - you induce priority inversion. Be sure to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/MIDIServices/CompositePage.html)

Comment: If you would be open to it, I have a github application I made to demonstrate my problem..  Can I communicate with you somehow outside of here?

Comment: If you like so, please feel free to open a chat here.

Comment: I opened a new question that is more specific... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328670/timestamps-on-midipacket-do-not-seem-to-be-right

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AVAudioEngine.musicSequence` and prepare your audio unit graph. Then use the [MusicSequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009331-CH2-SW22) API to load your GM file. Like this you don’t need to do the timing by yourself. Note I have not done this myself so far but I understand in theory it should work like this.

After you instantiate your synthesizer audio unit, you attach and connect it to the `AVAudioEngine` graph.

> Does this mean, use @synchronize to do thread blocking for safety?

The opposite of what you’ve said is true: You should certainly not lock in a realtime thread. The `@synchronized` directive will lock if the resource is already locked. You may consider to use lock-free queues for realtime threads. See also [Four common mistakes in audio development](http://atastypixel.com/blog/four-common-mistakes-in-audio-development/).

If you have to use CoreMIDI and `MIDIReadProc`, you can send MIDI commands to the synthesizer audio unit by calling `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent` right from your callback.